# How to execute Ansible tasks in IF ELSE mode?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have following code where in I want to implement conditional logic like if-else construct:

```yaml
- name: Download katello agent package
  get_url:
    url: "{{ abc_url }}/pub/yyy.rpm"
    dest: "{{ tmp_dir }}"
```

`when: 'rt' in group_names` url = abc_url,
`when: 'rt' not in group_names` url = def_url, based on `group_names`, my URL changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***I want to implement conditional logic like if-else construct***

It depends on the circumstances. But in the Use Case shown, no, one won't to do so in Ansible. It is not recommended to implement a conditional logic in such a case. Instead one should use the inventory and `group_vars`.

For an inventory file **`example.com`**

```ini
[rt]
a.example.com
b.example.com
c.example.com

[def]
d.example.com
e.example.com
f.example.com
```

and **`group_vars`** files

```bash
tree group_vars/
group_vars/
├── def
│   └── katello
├── rt
│   └── katello
└── all
```

with content of

**`cat group_vars/rt/katello`**

```yaml
URL: abc.example.com
```

**`cat group_vars/def/katello`**

```yaml
URL: def.example.com
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ URL }}"
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook --inventory example.com main.yml
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********
ok: [a.example.com] =>
  msg: abc.example.com
ok: [c.example.com] =>
  msg: abc.example.com
ok: [b.example.com] =>
  msg: abc.example.com

ok: [d.example.com] =>
  msg: def.example.com
ok: [f.example.com] =>
  msg: def.example.com
ok: [e.example.com] =>
  msg: def.example.com
```

As one can see from the output, no IF THEN ELSE, no [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) or `when`, no `set_fact` or tasks, no code, no programming at all. Just and only [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html).

**Further Reading and Documentation**

- [Things to know about programming using Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-coding-programming)

  > *Ansible is not a language:
  > If Ansible isn't a programming language, then what is it? Ansible is a tool written in Python, and it uses the declarative markup language YAML to describe the Desired State of devices and configuration. ... You declare aspects you want to be configured on a target device, such as that a file or directory exists, a package is installed, a service is running, and so on.*
- [Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials)

  > *Think declaratively: Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.*
- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Congrats on 10k, by the way!

Answer (score 1):

To insert the conditional logic inline:

```yaml
- name: Download katello agent package
  get_url:
    url: "{{ 'abc_url' if 'rt' in group_names else 'def_url' }}/pub/yyy.rpm"
    dest: "{{ tmp_dir }}"
```

Though this should work, you can use the inventory and `group_vars`.
Set up an INI file e.g. `inventory.ini`

```ini
[rt_group] 
rt_host ansible_host=your_rt_host

[other_group] 
other_host ansible_host=your_other_host

[all:vars] 
abc_url=http://example.com/abc
def_url=http://example.com/def 
tmp_dir=/path/to/destination
```

And your playbook (`your_playbook.yml`):

```yaml
- name: Download katello agent package   
  hosts: all

  tasks:

  - name: Set URL based on group
    set_fact:
      download_url: "{{ abc_url }}"
    when: "'rt_group' in group_names"

  - name: Set URL based on group
    set_fact:
      download_url: "{{ def_url }}"
    when: "'rt_group' not in group_names"

  - name: Download package
    get_url:
      url: "{{ download_url }}/pub/yyy.rpm"
      dest: "{{ tmp_dir }}"
```

Comment: It is not recommended to implement a conditional logic in such case. Instead one should use his inventory and group_vars. Maybe you can add an example regarding that in your answer.

Comment: @U880D Can I not apply the conditional block as stated in this answer? How to do it using inventory and group_vars

Comment: Of course it is technically possible, however, since Ansible is a Desired State Configuration mostly it is not recommended to „program“ in it. For such it was never mentioned for.

Comment: @U880D Thanks for letting me know. Can you please guide me how to apply this conditional logic using group_vars/inventory?

Comment: I've tried a few times to get rid of the dots that should be dashes, so keep this in mind.